# Firebase Remote Config does not get the console values in OnComplete

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Up to now, my code worked perfectly. I was able to get the values set up in the Firebase console immediately after I changed them in this console (I paid attention to activate the Firebase developer mode to avoid cache + I do not forget to click on the console button to put the new values in production)

Since today, I am no more able to get the values set in the Firebase console in my OnComplete delegate method.

The OnComplete is launched but when I get the value, I get an old value. When I create a new value in the console, I get a empty value in OnComplete.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks !

Comment: There was a bug we reported some time ago and fix will be published only in next release. If you are using initialization without the json files for environment and you are initializing the firebase manually with init then remote config values are not fetched sadly.

Comment: What is strange is that everything worked perfectly until today. I have the google-services.json file (is it the file you are speaking about?). What do you mean by "initializing the firebase manually with init " ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes when we moved from Google services json file to manually initializing of the firebase during app start remote config got broken. Sadly then this is not the case for you l. I suggest you open a ticket for firebase team they are very responsive and polite.

Comment: Found the error! For some other tests, I set the time on my phone to a time/date in the past...(and forgot that I did this) Firebase Remote Config did not like it ! Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error! For some other tests, I set the time on my phone to a time/date in the past...(and forgot that I did this) Firebase Remote Config did not like it !